# Is it a good practice to inherit an interface from an base object?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

Code snippet explain this question better. This code snippet may not pass compile, but it well explain the question well.

From the code snippet, the interface INetworkAddressMonitor class inherit from Observerable to avoid 'Passing two object to other component'.

So the `INetwworkAddressMonitor` have two responsibility,

- Decouple.
- Reuse the `Observerable` code.

Is this an good practice? If not, how to handle it?

```
template <typename IObserverT> class Observerable
{
public:
    virtual ~Observerable(){}
    virtual void addObserver(IObserverT* obj) { ... }
    virtual void removeObserver(IObserverT* obj) { ... }
private:
    ...
};

class INetworkAddressMonitorListener
{
public:
    virtual void onXXXX() = 0;
};

// We don't want to pass NetworkAddressMonitor to another object,
// so we define INetworkAddressMonitor.
// We inherit INetworkAddressMonitor from Observerable, to avoid 
// pass both Observerable object and INetworkAddressMonitor. 
// IS THIS AN GOOD PRACTICE?
class INetworkAddressMonitor: public Observerable<INetworkAddressMonitorListener>
{
public:
    virtual ~INetworkAddressMonitor() {};
    virtual void start() {};
    ... ...
};

class NetworkAddressMonitor: INetworkAddressMonitor
{
    ... ...
}
```

Comment: It depends, are you going to interact with your derived classes through a base object pointer / reference? Because if you are (and the virtual functions suggest you will), every single derived class is going to have a different base type, which makes polymorphism impossible. You may need a non-templated base class and an intermediate CRTP class if this is your plan.

Comment: @user657267, We will using the NetworkAddressMonitor by reference or pointer to INetworkAddressMonitor.

Comment: I'm the OP. I think this question should be migrate to Programmers Stack Exchange, it is about software design, and should got some response in Programmers. But I cannot migrate it to programmers, it just let me select sharpoint/dba/superuser, no programmers , so can you please help to migrate it to programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you are creating an object to be used by a variety of client applications, then just publishing the interface, rather than the whole object can provide useful encapsulation (information hiding).

If you have a collection of objects with similar functionality, e.g. multiple printer drivers, then using a common interface makes it easier for client applications to mix and match objects (e.g. different printers) without needing their own separate code for every different object.

Complex programs often define an interface for "add-ons" or "extensions" -- e.g. a filter for a graphic program.  You can then design your own add-on and the program can utilise its functionality without knowing any specific information about your specific add-on.

In the above cases, and many other similar cases, using an interface base class makes a lot of sense.  In other cases, it might not necessarily be a good idea.